# Delete em uma trigger de UPDATE

Tags: mysql, trigger, sql-update, delete

Como posso deletar um registro que está sendo inserido em uma condição específica em uma trigger?

exemplo:

```
USE `scompraslenovo`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `precad_fornecedor_BUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON `precad_fornecedor` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (new.f1 IS NULL) AND (new.f2 IS NULL) AND (new.f3 IS NULL) THEN
        DELETE FROM precad_fornecedor
        WHERE precad_fornecedor.codigo = NEW.codigo;
    END IF;
END
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer funcionar?

Comment: Esse código só executa quando você atualiza um registro, e não quando você insere.

Comment: Apagando a trigger?

Comment: Apagar a trigger só vai fazer com que a ação que ela executa não ocorra.

Comment: Exatamente, se a trigger esta inserindo um registro, e ele quer apagar esse registro, basta não inseri-lo, ou seja não executar a ação de inserção, ou apagar a trigger

Comment: Poderiam editar o código pra ver como ficaria neste caso?

Answer (score 3):

"Deletar um registro que está sendo inserido" não faz muito sentido. Se vc vai deletar o registro que vai inserir, é mais prático não inseri-lo né? Então no caso você gostaria de impedir que determinado registro, caso não atenda as condições, não seja inserido certo? 
Nesse caso, é só vc trocar update por insert e colocar as condições.

```
USE `scompraslenovo`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `precad_fornecedor_BUPD` before insert ON `precad_fornecedor` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF ...
Where... 
END IF;
END
```

antes de inserir, a trigger vai pesquisar as condições. Caso não atenda, o registro não será inserido. Evitando a inserção pra depois a exclusão.